# regex in javascript, match only A-z and _?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello this is the first time I've worked with regex before and I'm attempting to take a variable entered by the user and see if it is limited to A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and _

this is the code I have so far:

```
function validateCSV(x){
    var y = document.getElementById('column').value;
    var pattern = new RegExp('^\b\w\b$');
    if(!pattern.test(y)){
       alert("Use only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or _ in column names.");
       return false;
    }
}
```

As far as I was aware using \w would match any alphanumeric and underscore but no white space, which is exactly what I wanted. However even if I only have something like test1 or test it still doesn't seem to work correctly, as it still pops up my alert and doesn't let me continue. Any information on this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a quantifier, and you should use regex literal:

```
/^\w+$/
```

Comment: You should escape those backslashes or use a regex literal: `/^\b\w+\b$/`

Comment: You can remove the word boundaries that are useless.

Comment: perfect, simple, exactly what I was looking for! with Blender's suggestion and your advice it works perfectly!! thanks both of you!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte. Thanks. Missed that :)

Answer (score 3):

Your current regex is looking for a single word character (by definition, `\b` will assert to true when used at the start and end of the match).

I think the regex you're looking for is `/^[a-z0-9_]+$/i`

Note that you can use different things for that `+`:

- `+` one or more characters
- `*` zero or more characters, basically same as `+` but also allows empty string
- `{5}` exactly five characters
- `{3,16}` between three and sixteen characters (inclusive)

Vary as needed!

Comment: This was extremely useful, the only reason I'm choosing Rohit Jain's answer over yours is it is shorter and came in first, but very awesome information, thank you!!

Comment: @Kynian: You should choose the best answer, not the one that came first or is the shortest (although the best one may very well be both).

Comment: @Kynian If the "first" or "shortest" answer were the one you should accept, there'd be no reason for people to write detailed or researched answers. As Blender says, it should be the best one. Blender, thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining your regex from a string literal, which means the backslashes need to be escaped. You need:

```
new RegExp('^\\b\\w\\b$');
```

Or just use a regex literal:

```
var pattern = /^\b\w\b$/;
```

Which leads to your next problem: the regex will match a single `\w` character. You need to follow that with `*` to match zero or more, or a `+` to match one or more.

And the `\b` parts aren't needed at all:

```
var pattern = /^\w*$/;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VFyug/

In general, defining a regex using `new RegExp()` and a string is clunkier than a regex literal and I would only use it if the regex actually is coming from a string variable because, e.g., it needs to include text entered by the user.